# Holding information about table fields for a class

Tags: php, class, field

My application has many classes at this point. I want to save a bunch of work by defining information about the fields/properties once, and then use that everywhere else for inserting, updating, deleting and even logging data.

Take a look at this code:

```
protected $_visible_array = array(0 => 'No', 1 => 'Yes');

protected $_type_array = array(1 => 'Small', 2 => 'Medium', 3 => 'Large');

public function field_array() {
    $array['visible'] = info_array('cmp_visible', 'int', 'Visible', $_visible_array);
    $array['type'] = info_array('cmp_type', 'int', 'Type', $_type_array);
    $array['name'] = info_array('cmp_name', 'string', 'Name');
    $array['desc'] = info_array('cmp_desc', 'string', 'Description');
    return $array;
    }
```

My info_array function basically creates an array from the 4 parameters with the indexes 'column', 'type', 'label', 'options' so that I can get these values easily later on.

The first question I have is if it is possible to have something like:

```
protected $_options['visible] = array(0 => 'No', 1 => 'Yes');
```

This way I wouldn't have to pass in that 4th parameter to the info_array function as I would be able to access this array using the "visible" index
The problem is that I get PHP errors when trying this, not sure why...

I currently have get methods for all my properties, but I was wondering if having something like the following is okay:

```
    public function get($field) {
    return $this->$field;
    }
```

I want to be able to use the index from my field_array to get the value of that property.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're suggesting sounds like a good plan.

It's worth looking at magic functions `__get()` and `__set()` as I think you'll be able to make some even nicer abstraction using it.

I would probably create an abstract class that contains the magic methods and forces you to define the meta information for the fields (your `$_options` array) in a concrete class.

Your concrete class would then only have to define the meta information for the fields and off you go.

Comment: I read about the magic methods and supposedly they help when you don't  have access to a method due to it being private. Do you agree with the guy below that having a get($field) method is not good practice?